# In ILGenerator, calls to internal setters fail

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

To be able to manipulate properties at runtime, I am trying to build a generic wrapper  that would convert all public/non-public , static/instance properties into public instance properties visible in PropertyGrid control.

The code below works fine for public setters and getters (both static and instance), yet fails for, say, setters having internal scope.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public static class PropertyWrapper<T> where T : class
{
    public const BindingFlags DefaultBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public
                                                  | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                  | BindingFlags.Static
                                                  | BindingFlags.Instance;

    public static object Instance(T obj)
    {
        return Instance(obj, true, DefaultBindingFlags);
    }

    public static object Instance(T obj, bool readOnly)
    {
        return Instance(obj, readOnly, DefaultBindingFlags);
    }

    public static object Instance(T wrappedObject, bool readOnly, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
    {
        string commonName = "propertyWrapperModule.dll";
        FieldAttributes fieldAttributes = FieldAttributes.Public;

        string wrapperTypeName          = wrappedObject.GetType().Name + "_WRAPPER";
        AssemblyName assemblyName       = new AssemblyName { Name = "commonName" };
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder     = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(commonName);
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder         = moduleBuilder.DefineType(wrapperTypeName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

        var objProperties = wrappedObject.GetType().GetProperties(bindingFlags);
        foreach (var objProperty in objProperties)
        {
            // Field
            FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(objProperty.Name, objProperty.PropertyType, fieldAttributes);

            // Property
            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(objProperty.Name,
                                                PropertyAttributes.None,
                                                objProperty.PropertyType,
                                                new Type[] { objProperty.PropertyType });

            // Define Getter
            if (objProperty.CanRead)
            {
                MethodInfo objGetterMethodInfo = objProperty.GetGetMethod(true);

                if (objGetterMethodInfo != null)
                {
                    MethodBuilder getterMethodBuilder = DefineGetter(objGetterMethodInfo, typeBuilder, fieldBuilder);
                    propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethodBuilder);
                }
            }

            // Define Setter
            if (objProperty.CanWrite)
            {
                MethodInfo objSetterMethodInfo = objProperty.GetSetMethod(true);

                if (objSetterMethodInfo != null)
                {
                    MethodBuilder methodBuilderSetter = DefineSetter(objSetterMethodInfo, typeBuilder, fieldBuilder);       // , objectType);
                    propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(methodBuilderSetter);
                }
            }
        }

        Type wrapperType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        var wrapperObject = Activator.CreateInstance(wrapperType);

        // Test
        var wrapperProperties = wrapperType.GetProperties();

        // Save assembly
        assemblyBuilder.Save(commonName);

        return wrapperObject;

    }   // public object CreateNewObject(T obj) 


    private static MethodBuilder DefineGetter(MethodInfo getterMethodInfo, TypeBuilder typeBuilder, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)  //  Type objectType)
    {
        MethodAttributes attributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName;  // | MethodAttributes.Virtual;

        MethodBuilder getterMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod
        (
            getterMethodInfo.Name,
            attributes,
            getterMethodInfo.ReturnType,
            Type.EmptyTypes
        );

        // Generate IL
        ILGenerator ilGenerator = getterMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.DeclareLocal(fieldBuilder.FieldType);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        if (!getterMethodInfo.IsStatic)
        {
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        }
        ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, getterMethodInfo, null);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766839/using-br-s-opcode-to-point-to-next-instruction-using-reflection-emit-label
        Label targetInstruction = ilGenerator.DefineLabel();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, targetInstruction);
        ilGenerator.MarkLabel(targetInstruction);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return getterMethodBuilder;
    }

    private static MethodBuilder DefineSetter(MethodInfo setterMethodInfo, TypeBuilder typeBuilder, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)  
    {
        MethodAttributes attributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName;  

        MethodBuilder setterMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod
        (
            setterMethodInfo.Name,
            attributes,
            null,
            new Type[] { fieldBuilder.FieldType }
        );

        // Generate IL
        ILGenerator ilGenerator = setterMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        if (!setterMethodInfo.IsStatic)
        {
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        }
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ilGenerator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, setterMethodInfo, null);
        ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return setterMethodBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessibility rules are enforced by the CLR, you cannot bypass it with emit.

Comment: Hi Hans! Correct me if I am wrong, but it’s possible to call non-public methods using Reflection… Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, Reflection allows breaking the rules, assuming proper access rights.  It doesn't have anything to do with Reflection.Emit, it doesn't use IL.

Comment: Thanks Hans! So, is there any way to solve my problem to manipulate non-public properties in generic way?

Comment: Well, you could emit calls to reflection methods to call the relevant methods using reflection...

Comment: this is old questions buy I dont anything of the answers are correct. When generating code using the LCG ie DynamicMethod there is a constructor overload that says if visibility checks should be skipped. For normal SRE there is no option

Answer (score 1):

This will do that

```
public static Type BuildWrapper(object targetObject)
{
    Type targetWrapType = targetObject.GetType();

    string nameOfDLL = "magicWrapper.dll";
    string nameOfAssembly = "magic_Assembly";
    string nameOfModule = "magic_Module";
    string nameOfType = "magic_Type";


    System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName {Name = nameOfAssembly};
    System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder =
        System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName,
                                                                  System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.
                                                                      RunAndSave);
    System.Reflection.Emit.ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(nameOfModule, nameOfDLL);
    System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(nameOfType,
                                                                              System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.
                                                                                  Public |
                                                                              System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Class);


    System.Reflection.Emit.FieldBuilder targetWrapedObjectField =
        typeBuilder.DefineField("_" + targetWrapType.FullName.Replace(".", ""), targetWrapType,
                                System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.Private);
    System.Reflection.MethodAttributes constructorAttributes = System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public;

    Type objType = Type.GetType("System.Object");
    System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo objCtor = objType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    System.Reflection.Emit.ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder =
        typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(constructorAttributes, System.Reflection.CallingConventions.Standard,
                                      new Type[] {targetWrapType});

    System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator ilConstructor = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Call, objCtor);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Nop);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Stfld, targetWrapedObjectField);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Nop);
    ilConstructor.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);


    System.Reflection.MethodAttributes propertyAttributes = System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Public |
                                                            System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
                                                            System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.SpecialName;

    foreach (var prop in targetObject.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        string Name = prop.Name;
        Type DataType = prop.FieldType;

        System.Reflection.Emit.PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(Name,
                                                                                            System.Reflection.
                                                                                                PropertyAttributes.
                                                                                                SpecialName,
                                                                                            DataType, null);
        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder methodBuilderGetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + Name,
                                                                                            propertyAttributes,
                                                                                            DataType, new Type[] {});
        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder methodBuilderSetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + Name,
                                                                                            propertyAttributes,
                                                                                            typeof (void),
                                                                                            new Type[] {DataType});

        System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator ilGeneratorGetter = methodBuilderGetter.GetILGenerator();
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldfld, targetWrapedObjectField);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldfld, prop);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);


        System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator ilGeneratorSetter = methodBuilderSetter.GetILGenerator();
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldfld, targetWrapedObjectField);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Stfld, prop);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(methodBuilderGetter);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(methodBuilderSetter);
    }


    System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> PropertieList = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    PropertieList.AddRange(targetObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public));
    PropertieList.AddRange(targetObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    foreach (var prop in PropertieList)
    {
        string Name = prop.Name;
        Type DataType = prop.PropertyType;

        System.Reflection.Emit.PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(Name,
                                                                                            System.Reflection.
                                                                                                PropertyAttributes.
                                                                                                SpecialName,
                                                                                            DataType, null);
        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder methodBuilderGetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + Name,
                                                                                            propertyAttributes,
                                                                                            DataType, new Type[] {});
        System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder methodBuilderSetter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + Name,
                                                                                            propertyAttributes,
                                                                                            typeof (void),
                                                                                            new Type[] {DataType});

        System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator ilGeneratorGetter = methodBuilderGetter.GetILGenerator();
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldfld, targetWrapedObjectField);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetGetMethod());
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        ilGeneratorGetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);


        System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator ilGeneratorSetter = methodBuilderSetter.GetILGenerator();
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldfld, targetWrapedObjectField);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Callvirt, prop.GetSetMethod());
        ilGeneratorSetter.Emit(System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(methodBuilderGetter);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(methodBuilderSetter);
    }

    // Yes! you must do this, it should not be needed but it is!
    Type dynamicType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    // Save to file
    assemblyBuilder.Save(nameOfDLL);
    return dynamicType;
}
```